# Use first post as start-page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Is there an easy way to redirect the user to the first post when they go to the WordPress installation's main URL... Like, if the user goes to domain.com, they will be redirected to `domain.com/title-of-the-first-post`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of trying and failing, I was able to construct the following solution:

Add the following code to your *header.php*-file, located in *wp-content/themes/nameOfTheme*. Make sure there is no space or enter before the opening

```
<?php
if(is_home()) {
    $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
    $recentPosts->query('showposts=1');
    while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post();
    wp_redirect(get_permalink(), 301);
    endwhile;
}
?>
```

Comment: 301 is the HTTP code for "Moved Permanently" -- this doesn't seem appropriate for redirecting to the most recent post. You should probably use 302 Found instead.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Holmes answer of doing a redirect is a good one.

If htaccess is not an option, or you want to do it within WordPress, you can add simple logic to index.php using is_home_page(), and wp_redirect().
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

If you are not really looking to program a solution, I imagine this is a good question for https://superuser.com/
Maybe, you are looking for http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Answer (score 0):

Use your .htaccess file and do a [redirect](http://www.adminaddict.net/forum/vbulletin/htaccess-redirect-pointing-url-another-url-4324/)